# Cake php 3 | belongsToMany error while saving

Tags: associations, cakephp-3.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have below 3 tables

**sub-ambiences**

id | other fields

**restaurant-branches**

id | other fields

**restaurant_branches_sub_ambiences**

id | restaurant_branch_id | sub_ambience_id

I am adding the restaurant_branches and want to save associations

in **restaurantBranches/add.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->control('sub_ambiences._id', ['options' => $subAmbiences,'label' => false, 'multiple' => 'multiple']); ?>
```

**add() function in controller**

```
$restaurantBranch = $this->RestaurantBranches->patchEntity($restaurantBranch, $this->request->getData(), [
            'associated' => 'SubAmbiences'
        ]);
$this->RestaurantBranches->save($restaurantBranch)
```

while saving I am getting error

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value 
 INSERT INTO `sub_ambiences` (`created`, `modified`) VALUES (:c0, :c1)
```

please help

Comment: I think you want to use _ids, not _id, as the name of the input field.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Silly mistake. It worked. Thanks